# How to wrap function wpa_front_end_login in if/then statement

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I am using a plugin called "[Passwordless Login](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/add-ons/passwordless-login/)"

what it does is create a shortcode that you can add to any page, then that shortcode shows a text box where the user can input their email or username, then the plugin will check the users list and pull the user ID from the email/username and send them an email with the one-time login link which they can click on to be logged in and redirected to specific page (e.g. member's area).
Everything works fine with this plugin EXCEPT it sends duplicate email with login links; one link to login works but the other says "token expired". So the user is receiving two emails at the exact same time and only one of them has the login link that works.

I do NOT have the shortcode on the page twice or any other conflicts (it's on a blank page, just the shortcode). I tested the plugin on a blank new WP install and it still sends duplicate emails.

I am just trying to fix it so that it doesn't send duplicate emails!
Someone suggested to me the following but I don't know how to "wrap it in an if/then statement so that it only runs once"

**Sounds like it's just firing the wp_mail() function twice, once with the accurate info, and again with invalid/expired info. That usually means either the shortcode is on the page more than once, or another plugin using ob_start() is conflicting with it, possibly an SEO plugin.
If you absolutely can't figure out what is causing it to fire twice, you could always just wrap it in an if/then statement so that it only runs once, something like this:**

```
function wpa_front_end_login(){
    static $already_run = false;
    if ( $already_run !== true ) {
            //code goes here
    }
    $already_run = true;
}
```

Below is the passwordless_login.php file which needs to be fixed to not send duplicate emails. Can someone please wrap it in an if/then statement for me please or suggest something else. Thank you

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Passwordless Login
* Plugin URI: http://www.cozmsolabs.com
* Description: Shortcode based login form. Enter an email/username and get link via email that will automatically log you in.
* Version: 1.1.1
* Author: Cozmoslabs, sareiodata
* Author URI: http:/www.cozmoslabs.com
* License: GPL2
* Text Domain: passwordless-login
* Domain Path: /languages
*/
/* Copyright Cozmoslabs.com

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
published by the Free Software Foundation.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

// Start writing code after this line!


/**
 * Definitions
 *
 *
 */
define( 'PASSWORDLESS_LOGIN_VERSION', '1.1.1' );
define( 'WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
define( 'WPA_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

/**
 * Function that initiates the plugin text domain
 *
 * @since v.1.0.6
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpa_load_plugin_textdomain(){
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'passwordless-login', false, WPA_PLUGIN_URL . '/languages/' );
}
add_action('init', 'wpa_load_plugin_textdomain');


/**
 * Function that creates the "Basic Information" submenu page
 *
 * @since v.2.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpa_register_basic_info_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'users.php', __( 'Passwordless Login', 'passwordless-login' ), __( 'Passwordless Login', 'passwordless-login' ), 'manage_options', 'passwordless-login', 'wpa_basic_info_content' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpa_register_basic_info_submenu_page', 2 );

/**
 * Function that adds content to the "Passwordless Auth" submenu page
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpa_basic_info_content() {
?>
    <div class="wrap wpa-wrap wpa-info-wrap">
        <div class="wpa-badge <?php echo PASSWORDLESS_LOGIN_VERSION; ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Version %s', 'passwordless-login' ), PASSWORDLESS_LOGIN_VERSION ); ?></div>
        <h1><?php printf( __( '<strong>Passwordless Login</strong> <small>v.</small>%s', 'passwordless-login' ), PASSWORDLESS_LOGIN_VERSION ); ?></h1>
        <p class="wpa-info-text"><?php printf( __( 'A front-end login form without a password.', 'passwordless-login' ) ); ?></p>
        <p><strong style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle; color:#d54e21;"><?php echo get_option('wpa_total_logins', '0'); ?></strong> <?php _e('successful logins without passwords.', 'passwordless-login'); ?></p>
        <hr />
        <h2 class="wpa-callout"><?php _e( 'One time password for WordPress', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="wpa-row wpa-2-col">
            <div>
                <h3><?php _e( '[passwordless-login] shortcode', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></h3>
                <p><?php _e( 'Just place <strong class="nowrap">[passwordless-login]</strong> shortcode in a page or a widget and you\'re good to go.', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3><?php _e( 'An alternative to passwords', 'passwordless-login'  ); ?></h3>
                <p><?php _e( 'Passwordless Authentication <strong>dose not</strong> replace the default login functionality in WordPress. Instead you can have the two work in parallel.', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></p>
                <p><?php _e( 'Join the discussion here: <a href="http://www.cozmoslabs.com/?p=31550&utm_source=wpbackend&utm_medium=link&utm_content=link&utm_campaign=passwordless">WordPress Passwordless Authentication</a>', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>
            <h3><?php _e( 'Take control of the login and registration process with Profile Builder', 'passwordless-login' );?></h3>
            <p><?php _e( 'Improve upon Passwordless Authentication using the free <a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/">Profile Builder</a> plugin:', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></p>
            <div class="wpa-row wpa-3-col">
                <div><p><?php _e('Front-End registration, edit profile and login forms.', 'passwordless-login'); ?></p></div>
                <div><p><?php _e('Drag and drop to reorder / remove default user profile fields.', 'passwordless-login'); ?></p></div>
                <div><p><?php _e('Allow users to log in with their username or email.', 'passwordless-login'); ?></p></div>
                <div><p><?php _e('Enforce minimum password length and minimum password strength.', 'passwordless-login'); ?></p></div>
            </div>
            <p><a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/" class="button button-primary button-large"><?php _e( 'Learn More About Profile Builder', 'passwordless-login' ); ?></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}


/**
 * Add scripts and styles to the back-end
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpa_print_script( $hook ){
    if ( ( $hook == 'users_page_passwordless-login' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpa-back-end-style', WPA_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/style-back-end.css', false, PASSWORDLESS_LOGIN_VERSION );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_print_script' );

/**
 * Add scripts and styles to the front-end
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpa_add_plugin_stylesheet() {
    if (  file_exists( WPA_PLUGIN_DIR . '/assets/style-front-end.css' )  ){
        wp_register_style( 'wpa_stylesheet', WPA_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/style-front-end.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpa_stylesheet' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wpa_add_plugin_stylesheet' );

/**
 * Shortcode for the passwordless login form
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return html
 */
function wpa_front_end_login(){
    
    ob_start();
    $account = ( isset( $_POST['user_email_username']) ) ? $account = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_email_username'] ) : false;
    $nonce = ( isset( $_POST['nonce']) ) ? $nonce = sanitize_key( $_POST['nonce'] ) : false;
    $error_token = ( isset( $_GET['wpa_error_token']) ) ? $error_token = sanitize_key( $_GET['wpa_error_token'] ) : false;
    $adminapp_error = ( isset( $_GET['wpa_adminapp_error']) ) ? sanitize_key( $_GET['wpa_adminapp_error'] ) : false;

    $sent_link = wpa_send_link($account, $nonce);


    if( $account && !is_wp_error($sent_link) ){
        echo '<p class="wpa-box wpa-success">'. apply_filters('wpa_success_link_msg', __('Please check your email. You will soon receive an email with a login link.', 'passwordless-login') ) .'</p>';
    } elseif ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo '<p class="wpa-box wpa-alert">'.apply_filters('wpa_success_login_msg', sprintf(__( 'You are currently logged in as %1$s. %2$s', 'passwordless-login' ), '<a href="'.$authorPostsUrl = get_author_posts_url( $current_user->ID ).'" title="'.$current_user->display_name.'">'.$current_user->display_name.'</a>', '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( $redirectTo = wpa_curpageurl() ).'" title="'.__( 'Log out of this account', 'passwordless-login' ).'">'. __( 'Log out', 'passwordless-login').' &raquo;</a>' ) ) . '</p><!-- .alert-->';
    } else {
        if ( is_wp_error($sent_link) ){
            echo '<p class="wpa-box wpa-error">' . apply_filters( 'wpa_error', $sent_link->get_error_message() ) . '</p>';
        }
        if( $error_token ) {
            echo '<p class="wpa-box wpa-error">' . apply_filters( 'wpa_invalid_token_error', __('Your token has probably expired. Please check your email for another login link or try again.', 'passwordless-login') ) . '</p>';
        }
        if( $adminapp_error ) {//admin approval compatibility
            echo '<p class="wpa-box wpa-error">' . apply_filters( 'wpa_admin_approval_error', __('Your account needs to be approved by an admin before you can log-in.', 'passwordless-login') ) . '</p>';
        }
        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
        //Setting up the label for the password request form based on the Allows Users to Login With Profile Builder Option
        if (is_plugin_active('profile-builder-pro/index.php') || is_plugin_active('profile-builder/index.php') || is_plugin_active('profile-builder-hobbyist/index.php')) {
            $wppb_general_options = get_option('wppb_general_settings');

            if ($wppb_general_options !== false) {
                if ($wppb_general_options['loginWith'] == 'email')
                    $label = __('Login with email', 'passwordless-login') . '<br>';
                else if ($wppb_general_options['loginWith'] == 'username')
                    $label = __('Login with username', 'passwordless-login') . '<br>';
                else
                    $label = __('Login with email or username', 'passwordless-login');
            }
        }
        else
            $label = __('Login with email', 'passwordless-login');
        ?>
    <form name="wpaloginform" id="wpaloginform" action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="user_email_username"><?php echo( apply_filters('wpa_change_form_label', $label)) ; ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_email_username" id="user_email_username" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $account ); ?>" size="25" />
            <input type="submit" name="wpa-submit" id="wpa-submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Log In', 'passwordless-login'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php do_action('wpa_login_form'); ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wpa_passwordless_login_request', 'nonce', false ) ?>

    </form>
<?php
    }

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'passwordless-login', 'wpa_front_end_login' );

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

/**
 * Checks to see if an account is valid. Either email or username
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return bool / WP_Error
 */
function wpa_valid_account( $account ){
    if( is_email( $account ) ) {
        $account = sanitize_email( $account );
    } else {
        $account = sanitize_user( $account );
    }

    if( is_email( $account ) && email_exists( $account ) ) {
        return $account;
    }

    if( ! is_email( $account ) && username_exists( $account ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $account );
        if( $user ) {
            return $user->data->user_email;
        }
    }

    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_account', __( 'The username or email you provided do not exist. Please try again.', 'passwordless-login' ) );
}

/**
 * Sends an email with the unique login link.
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return bool / WP_Error
 */
function wpa_send_link( $email_account = false, $nonce = false ){
    if ( $email_account  == false ){
        return false;
    }
    $valid_email = wpa_valid_account( $email_account  );
    $errors = new WP_Error;
    if (is_wp_error($valid_email)){
        $errors->add('invalid_account', $valid_email->get_error_message());
    } else{
        $blog_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        $blog_name = esc_attr( $blog_name );

        //Filters to change the content type of the email
        add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', function(){ return "text/html"; } );

        $unique_url = wpa_generate_url( $valid_email , $nonce );
        $subject = apply_filters('wpa_email_subject', sprintf(__("Login at %s", 'passwordless-login'), sitename));
        $message = apply_filters('wpa_email_message', sprintf(__('Hello! <br><br>Login at %s by visiting this url: <a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'passwordless-login'),$blog_name, esc_url($unique_url), esc_url($unique_url)),$unique_url, $valid_email);
        $sent_mail = wp_mail( $valid_email, $subject, $message );

        if ( !$sent_mail ){
            $errors->add('email_not_sent', __('There was a problem sending your email. Please try again or contact an admin.', 'passwordless-login'));
        }
    }
    $error_codes = $errors->get_error_codes();

    if (empty( $error_codes  )){
        return false;
    }else{
        return $errors;
    }
}

/**
 * Generates unique URL based on UID and nonce
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpa_generate_url( $email = false, $nonce = false ){
    if ( $email  == false ){
        return false;
    }
    /* get user id */
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
    $token = wpa_create_onetime_token( 'wpa_'.$user->ID, $user->ID  );

    $arr_params = array( 'wpa_error_token', 'uid', 'token', 'nonce' );
    $url = remove_query_arg( $arr_params, wpa_curpageurl() );

    $url_params = array('uid' => $user->ID, 'token' => $token, 'nonce' => $nonce);
    $url = add_query_arg($url_params, $url);

    return $url;
}

/**
 * Automatically logs in a user with the correct nonce
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_autologin_via_url' );
function wpa_autologin_via_url(){
    if( isset( $_GET['token'] ) && isset( $_GET['uid'] ) && isset( $_GET['nonce'] ) ){
        $uid = sanitize_key( $_GET['uid'] );
        $token  =  sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['token'] );
        $nonce  = sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['nonce'] );

        $hash_meta = get_user_meta( $uid, 'wpa_' . $uid, true);
        $hash_meta_expiration = get_user_meta( $uid, 'wpa_' . $uid . '_expiration', true);
        $arr_params = array( 'uid', 'token', 'nonce' );
        $current_page_url = remove_query_arg( $arr_params, wpa_curpageurl() );

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
        $time = time();

        $wppb_generalSettings = get_option('wppb_general_settings', 'not_found');//profile builder settings are required for admin approval compatibility

        if ( ! $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($token . $hash_meta_expiration, $hash_meta) || $hash_meta_expiration < $time || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'wpa_passwordless_login_request' ) ){
            wp_redirect( $current_page_url . '?wpa_error_token=true' );
            exit;
        }else if ( defined('PROFILE_BUILDER_VERSION') && $wppb_generalSettings != 'not_found' && !empty( $wppb_generalSettings['adminApproval'] ) && $wppb_generalSettings['adminApproval'] == 'yes' && wp_get_object_terms( $uid, 'user_status' ) ){//admin approval compatibility
            wp_redirect( $current_page_url . '?wpa_adminapp_error=true' );
            exit;
        }
        else {
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $uid );
            delete_user_meta($uid, 'wpa_' . $uid );
            delete_user_meta($uid, 'wpa_' . $uid . '_expiration');

            $total_logins = get_option( 'wpa_total_logins', 0);
            update_option( 'wpa_total_logins', $total_logins + 1);

            if (function_exists('wppb_custom_redirect_url')){
                wp_redirect( 'https://www.example.ca/members' );
                exit;
            }

            wp_redirect( 'https://www.example.ca/members' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create a nonce like token that you only use once based on transients
 *
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpa_create_onetime_token( $action = -1, $user_id = 0 ) {
    $time = time();

    // random salt
    $key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
    $string = $key . $action . $time;

    // we're sending this to the user
    $token  = wp_hash( $string );
    $expiration = apply_filters('wpa_change_link_expiration', $time + 60*10);
    $expiration_action = $action . '_expiration';

    // we're storing a combination of token and expiration
    $stored_hash = $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $token . $expiration );

    update_user_meta( $user_id, $action , $stored_hash ); // adjust the lifetime of the token. Currently 10 min.
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $expiration_action , $expiration );
    return $token;
}

/**
 * Returns the current page URL
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpa_curpageurl() {
    $req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $home_path = trim( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
    $home_path_regex = sprintf( '|^%s|i', preg_quote( $home_path, '|' ) );

    // Trim path info from the end and the leading home path from the front.
    $req_uri = ltrim($req_uri, '/');
    $req_uri = preg_replace( $home_path_regex, '', $req_uri );
    $req_uri = trim(home_url(), '/') . '/' . ltrim( $req_uri, '/' );

    return $req_uri;
}


/**
 * Add notices on plugin activation.
 *
 * @since v.1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */

include_once("inc/wpa.class.notices.php");
$learn_more_notice = new WPA_Add_Notices(
    'wpa_learn_more',
    sprintf( __( '<p>Use [passwordless-login] shortcode in your pages or widgets. %1$sLearn more.%2$s  %3$sDismiss%4$s</p>', 'passwordless-login'), "<a href='users.php?page=passwordless-login&wpa_learn_more_dismiss_notification=0'>", "</a>", "<a href='". add_query_arg( 'wpa_learn_more_dismiss_notification', '0' ) ."' class='wpa-dismiss-notification' style='float:right;margin-left:20px;'> ", "</a>" ),
    'updated',  '', ''
);
```

Comment: I have tested this and working fine.

Comment: It must be a conflict with some other plugin I have, but regardless, can someone help me just wrap the function